# How to determine which queues a Celery worker is consuming at runtime?

Tags: python, celery

As part of a sanity check, I want to write some code to make sure the worker has started with a correct set of queues based on the settings given.

Celery is run like so:

```
celery worker -A my_app -l INFO -Q awesome_mode
```

I would like to work out after the app is initialised, which queues Celery is consuming.

e.g., I made up `app.queues`:

```
app = Celery('my_app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

if 'awesome_mode' in app.queues:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of interactive debugging I found `app.amqp.queues` which is a dictionary where the key is the name of the queue and the value is a `Queue`.

Unfortunately the dictionary is not populated immediately after initialisation, but does work after the `worker_ready` signal.

Placing this code after app initialisation seems to work. It could probably be placed elsewhere of course.

```
@worker_ready.connect
def worker_ready_handler(sender=None, **kwargs):
    print(app.amqp.queues.keys())
```

The worker logs:

```
[2015-04-22 07:41:01,147: WARNING/MainProcess] ['celery', 'awesome_mode']
[2015-04-22 07:41:01,148: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@zaptop ready.
```

Comment: That seems to be a list of all queues celery has. Not just the ones that the worker is consuming. If i started a celery worker with only "awesome_mode it would give the same result